# JOOQ generated records set to implement Record4 interface even when set not to

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am using this genrator setup to create my jooq record objects

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.0.0.xsd">
    <jdbc>
        <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/local</url>
        <user>a</user>
        <password>b</password>
    </jdbc>
    <generator>
        <name>org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator</name>
        <database>
            <name>org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase</name>
            <includes>.*</includes>
            <excludes></excludes>
            <recordVersionFields></recordVersionFields>
            <recordTimestampFields></recordTimestampFields>
            <dateAsTimestamp>false</dateAsTimestamp>
            <unsignedTypes>true</unsignedTypes>
            <inputSchema>local</inputSchema>
            <outputSchema>heroku_abc</outputSchema>
        </database>
        <generate>
            <relations>true</relations>
            <deprecated>true</deprecated>
            <instanceFields>true</instanceFields>
            <generatedAnnotation>true</generatedAnnotation>
            <records>true</records>
            <pojos>false</pojos>
            <immutablePojos>false</immutablePojos>
            <interfaces>false</interfaces>
            <daos>false</daos>
            <jpaAnnotations>false</jpaAnnotations>
            <validationAnnotations>false</validationAnnotations>
            <globalObjectReferences>true</globalObjectReferences>
        </generate>
        <target>
            <packageName>dk.foo.entities.generated</packageName>
            <directory>/home/user/Development/git/dp/src/main/java/</directory>
        </target>
    </generator>
</configuration>
```

I can't seem to understand why my generated records implements the Record4 interface.
while the record is marked as implementing the interface, it has no implementation of its method resulting in this error message from my IDE - eclipse:

The type BjCategoriesRecord must implement the inherited abstract method

```
Record4<Integer,Integer,String,Byte>.values(Integer, Integer, String, Byte)
```

One of my records:

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(value    = { "http://www.jooq.org", "3.1.0" },
                            comments = "This class is generated by jOOQ")
@java.lang.SuppressWarnings({ "all", "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public class CategoriesRecord extends org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl<dk.foo.entities.generated.tables.records.CategoriesRecord> implements org.jooq.Record4<java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String, java.lang.Byte> {
```

EDIT: 
A little look further made this more clear to me.
If I ask eclipse to add the unimplemented methods i'll get 4 of these:

```
@Override
    public Record4<Integer, Integer, String, Byte> value1(Integer value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

The above signature just doesn't match the ones that otherwise were previously created using code generator...

```
/**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public java.lang.Integer value1() {
        return getId();
    }
```

this makes me think of some version mismatch of some sort. The codegen uses 3.0.0 and my project depends on 3.3.0 and the generated records informs me that 3.1.0 was used. What a mess..

Comment: *"The codegen uses 3.0.0 and my project depends on 3.3.0 and the generated records informs me that 3.1.0 was used. What a mess"* - so did this resolve your issue, then? :-)

Comment: Hello Lukas, yes it did... i am using Ben Manes latest release of the jooq-gradle-plugin, which uses 3.1.0 - latest update. I've downgraded my dependencies to 3.1 instead of the latest jOOQ 3.3.0 and it works all fine. I was wondering, do you have any update regarding the incorporation of his plugin into jOOQ? i can't find the jooq-gradle-codegen package (not sure about its name ;-) )

Comment: Ben Manes doesn't maintain this plugin any longer. Without a signed CLA, we could not incorporate (and maintain) his plugin...

Comment: @LukasEder Do I get this right that currently jOOQ does not provide code generation plugin for Gradle?

Comment: Not out of the box, but [you can find some interesting hints on the user group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jooq-user/NfQYxd7CJiA/33NweIMwH0oJ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just adapted my dependencies to include the proper version of jooq, jooq-meta and jooq-codegen  to use the same version as Ben Manes' pluggin, [jooq-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-jooq-plugin)

Comment: Note, [there is also a more recent contribution by Etienne Studer](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin)